# GA Funnel weird traffic flow behavior

Tags: google-analytics

This is the screen-shot of my GA goal setup [goal_setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkhDM.png) and this is the screen-shot of my goal funnel [goal_funnel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf77m.png).

The first step in my funnel is **/travel-insurance** the problem is, majority of traffic is exiting from the first step to **/travel-insurance** (which is the first step).
It would be great if someone could explain why is this happening, I have read google docs on this and found no explanation.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The way GA identifies user flow is: user visits page A, then page B and revisits page A. It might see it as 2 sessions - one moving from page A to page B and one leaving page B (going to step A). If for some reason page A refreshes automatically or users refresh it, it could show users "leaving" page A to page A.

I recommend testing the user flow (or creating a user segment to identify those users that "leave" step 1) to see if the page refreshes which could cause the issue.